# Create a devise user from Ruby console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Any idea on how to create and save a new User object with devise from the ruby console?

When I tried to save it, I'm getting always false. I guess I'm missing something but I'm unable to find any related info.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, and you probably already know about Railcasts, but I found these video's useful when learning about Devise: http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise, http://railscasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise. They have a few more really useful videos about Devise on there too. Good luck.

Comment: Yea i watched them both, but they don't say anything about what i'm asking.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

You can add false to the save method to skip the validations if you want.

```
User.new({:email => "guy@gmail.com", :roles => ["admin"], :password => "111111", :password_confirmation => "111111" }).save(false)
```

Otherwise I'd do this

```
User.create!({:email => "guy@gmail.com", :roles => ["admin"], :password => "111111", :password_confirmation => "111111" })
```

If you have `confirmable` module enabled for devise, make sure you are setting the `confirmed_at` value to something like `Time.now` while creating.

Comment: Looks like save(false) is depcreated, now should be save(:validate => false)

Comment: there is just so much magic happening here.. The User model extends Active Record. how come the create method is overriden. Where is the password being encrypted?

Comment: What does the devise call actually do

Comment: Seems like a wrong way of doing. This way of forcibly validating (or skipping validation) won't set the encrypted_password, hence making this record useless in the real app.

Answer (score 80):

You should be able to do this using

```
u = User.new(:email => "user@name.com", :password => 'password', :password_confirmation => 'password')
u.save
```

if this returns false, you can call

```
u.errors
```

to see what's gone wrong.

Comment: If you use :confirmable, don't forget to also set :confirmed_at attribute to Time.now so you can log in right away.

Comment: As a shortcut, if you're using `Confirmable`, call `u.confirm!`

Answer (score 30):

When on your model has :confirmable option this mean the object user should be confirm first. You can do two ways to save user.

a. first is skip confirmation:

```
newuser = User.new({email: 'superadmin1@testing.com', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password'})
newuser.skip_confirmation!
newuser.save
```

b. or use confirm! :

```
newuser = User.new({email: 'superadmin2@testing.com', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password'})
newuser.confirm!
newuser.save
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to **avoid sending confirmation emails**, the best choice is:

```
    u = User.new({
      email: 'demo@greenant.com.br',
      password: '12feijaocomarroz',
      password_confirmation: '12feijaocomarroz'
    })

    u.confirm
    u.save
```

So if you're using a fake email or have no internet connection, that'll avoid errors.

Comment: Update: `confirm!` is now just `confirm`

Answer (score 3):

None of the above answers worked for me.

This is what I did:

```
User.create(email: "a@a.com", password: "asdasd", password_confirmation: "asdasd")
```

Keep in mind that the password must be bigger than 6 characters.