# Using devise in a dev environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I just inherited a rails project using devise. In production you can send a user a invitation with an invitation token. Does devise have a way to set up a dummy invitation token? In other words is there known way to deal with all of devises different authentication systems in a dev environment?

Thanks

Comment: You can could create a user manually in the rails console

Comment: You can create a user from the console: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316940/create-a-devise-user-from-ruby-console or you can use the registration form and the confirmation mail will be displayed in the debug output of your rails development server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my development environment I turn email off.  Then create new users, whether invitation guest users or standard users with the form - then check my logs for the email sent to user and grab the invitation link.

in `config/environments/development.rb'  change:

```
 config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
```

to

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :false
```

Then you can grab the email body from the logs and use the link.

You can always change the token if you need to.

```
User.resend_invitation!(:email => "joeblow@lalaland.com")
```

You can also work it from the command line side:

```
User.invite!(:email => "joeblow@lalaland.com", :name => "Joe Blow")
```

To skip the user email you can do:

```
User.invite!(:email => "joeblow@lalaland.com", :name => "Joe Blow") { |user| user.skip_invitation => true }
```

And to accept it from the command line:

```
u = User.find_by_email("joeblow@lalaland.com")
User.accept_invitation!(:invitation_token => u.invitation_token, :password => "ad97nwj3o2")
```